# Row's derivative according to black point in image (opencv)

Tags: opencv, derivative

Hi I have this image's row

[image]

And I should get this row's derivative for black point But I dont know How can I do it

Comment: This can't be a single row. _Height_ of a single row is just 1 pixel, so you can't have diagonal boundaries. And if you want to compute the derivatives, you can use Sobel or the like on the whole image

Comment: Yes you are rigth I changed image Its a roı not row Im sorry

Comment: [if you want to compute the derivatives, you can use Sobel or the like](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html)

Comment: but sobel or like has a integer pixel I want to  have like these pixel(2.5,9.6) (4.1,6.3)

Comment: Actetually I want to find subpixel and so I think an algorithm 1) separete rows from image 2) derivative for black point(image is black an white colour only)3) According to step 2 I get two point for each rows and finally I fit function with neighboors two point and I get first derivative for 0(zero) @Miki

Comment: No... Use sobel.. You can then interpolate (eventually) to get derivatives with subpix accuracy

Comment: However, what are you  trying to do? This looks like an xy problem to me

Comment: What I mean is that I should use sobel and than get derivatives shouldn't I In addition when I try previous comment I have an error becouse only x point has subpixel y point hasn't it like (9.2,0)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't follow you on this one... Good luck!